# Regex to match the end of line

Tags: regex, bash

I am looking for BASH regex to pull the 'db' agruments from the below commands. The order of the arguments is not guaranteed however. For some reason I cannot get it to work completely.

What I have so far

```
regex="--db (.*)($| --)"
[[ $@ =~ $regex ]]
DB_NAMES="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"

# These are example lines
somecommand --db myDB --conf /var/home # should get "myDB"
somecommand --db myDB anotherDB manymoreDB --conf /home # should get "myDB anotherDB manymoreDB" 
somecommand --db myDB # should get "myDB"
somecommand --db myDB anotherDB # should get "myDB anotherDB"
```

Any suggestion on the regex?

Comment: i don't think bash supports non-greedy match. you can try either `([^-]*)` instead of `(.*)`, or use awk or sed

Comment: Why not use `getopt` or `getopts` for command line arguments parsing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `bash` uses a flavor of `regex` that does not include non-greedy repetition operators (`*?`, `+?`). Because `*` is greedy and there is no way to tell it to not be greedy, the first parenthesized subexpression (`(.*)`) matches everything up to the end of line.

You can work around this if you know for that the values you want to capture do not contain a certain character and replace `.` with the character class that excludes that character.

For example, if the values after `--db` do not contain dashes (`-`) you can use this `regex`:

```
regex='--db ([^-]*)($| --)'
```

It matches all the examples posted in the question.

Answer (score 2):

The following works:

```
regex="--db[[:space:]]([[:alnum:][:space:]]+)([[:space:]]--|$)"
[[ "$@" =~ $regex ]]
```

There were two issues:

1. Character classes such as [:space:] should be used to represent whitespace
2. `(.*)` is greedy and will go as far as your last `--` literal. Since bash doesn't support non-greedy matching, we have to match using `[[:alnum:][:space:]]` which will guarantee we stop at the next `--`.

Comment: @axiac - ah, I had assumed the RegEx was correct, and the quotes were causing the issue. Fixed the regex as well, thanks.

Comment: The quotes do not cause any harm. I ran the code posted in the question and it works for the last two examples. The problem is on the first two because the `regex` used by `bash` are greedy and I could not find any way (in the documentation) to make them not-greedy.

Answer (score 1):

By default, RegEx tries to get the most matches possible, use a non-greedy *(lazy)* quantifier. You might also want to put `--` first so the engine will use that first

```
--db[[:space:]](.*?)([[:space:]]--|$)
```

## [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bH6fR8/3)

---

If you don't want the `--`, you can use a non-capture group

```
--db[[:space:]](.*?)(?:[[:space:]]--|$)
                     ^^ Notice the ?:
```

## [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bH6fR8/4)

Comment: Bash doesn't support non-greedy.

Comment: Bash doesn't support non-capture groups either.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to match on non-space characters to catch the first grouping:

```
regex="--db (\S+)( --|$)"
```

Comment: bash doesn't do character classes with `\S` - although you can't have the regular expression quoted.